Replacing old Honeywell line voltage thermostat
My son's 1968 condominium has an old Honeywell T651A 2028 line voltage t-stat which controls the wall unit providing both heating and cooling. We are trying to update the t-stat with something a little more modern. From what I've read here and other places, the MYSA for baseboards should be compatible. Another option may be Honeywell's Residio B394118 although that connects via 4 wires where our current system runs on 3.
I contacted support at MYSA and they advised the following requirements for compatibility;

A minimum of 4 wires in the gangbox, excluding any attached to the current thermostats.
No relays, contactors, or power modules
No built-in digital controls on the heaters
Wattage can not exceed 3800 watts on a 240-volt circuit, 1900 watts on a 120-volt circuit
Breaker size is 20 amp
No safety timers built into the heater

I need to double check but I believe we meet those standards as while I have a 3 wire t-stat, there are four wires going into the gang box with pair joined and then wired into the t-stat. From an old video I found on you tube, I think our wiring looks like this:

Here's the back of the t-stat

Thanks in advance!

Mysa just replied again and advised their product only handles heating systems. Any chance that's a help desk person with no HVAC experience just working off a check sheet or is that likely the case?
